# Bokeh's box zoom resetting to pan intermittently

Tags: graph, data-science, visualization, bokeh

Has anyone encountered the problem where the 'box zoom' in bokeh gets automatically reset to 'pan' intermittently? I am unable to zoom in judiciously, as the reset is erratic.

I have installed bokeh 3.2.2 and am observing it here, but I also find this issue in bokeh 2.1.1.

Comment: I've never seen anything remotely like that, and I have been maintaining Bokeh for 12 years. Though I'm not entirely sure I understand exactly what you are seeing. I would recommend trying to obtain a video screen capture that demonstrates the behavior clearly, as well as providing a Minimal Reproducing Example and all relevant platform and browser versions.